# Obter minha localização através de reverseGeocodeLocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, gps

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês para resolver um problema, eu tenho um sistema de delivery que obtém minha localização utilizando GPS, andei lendo algo a respeito de "reverseGeocodeLocation", mas obtenho apenas um resultado mas nem sempre é o que eu estou no caso se eu estiver em minha casa no meio do quarteirão ele retorna o endereço mais próximo, alguém poderia me ajudar a fazer com que o sistema retorne as 4 ruas ao redor do bloco onde eu estou, meu app foi programado para IOS com a linguagem objective-c, se alguém poder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

```
CLLocation *crnLoc = [locations lastObject];
latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.latitude];
longitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.longitude];
altitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f m",crnLoc.altitude];
```

a altitude influência na precisão da localização.

Comment: Obrigado pela informação, mas no meu caso eu até consigo obter um resultado mas se eu estiver no meio de um bloco onde há 4 ruas em volta do bloco, como eu poderia obter essas quatro ruas, alguns apps fazem isso, um exemplo que funciona perfeito seria o Ifood.